# Cannot arrange my music by artist into libraries of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, music, windows-libraries

My problem is that in Windows 7, there are the libraries with Pictures, Music, Movies and Documents.

When I go into Music, I cannot arrange the music by Artists.
I can choose to arrange them by song, or by album, or by genre but when I click on artist, it does nothing.  It stays where it was before (by album for example).

This is my fault.

When I unchecked "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties", I clicked ok, but at the same time, (like 20 seconds after), I closed the service "Windows search", while Windows was still applying new attribute to files.

- I've restarted Windows search.
- Checked the "Allow files on this drive..."
- Waited.
- Rebuilt the index into indexing option.
- I've tried the trick with the windows media network sharing service too.
- It's all ok, except that I can't arrange my music by artist.
- I've removed the location of my folder my music into libraries options, then I moved all the files to another folder.
- All the tags of the mp3 are ok.  The information of the artist are all there.  Even Windows media player can see them and arrange them by artist into his own  program.  But I want to arrange them by artist into folder view, not a program.

If I type "artist:" into the windows search box at the top, it gives me all the results.

- I've even made a chkdsk to my drive.

I don't know what to do else.

Comment: There is an "Arrange by" option to the right side of Explorer in the Music library, that has *Folder* selected by default. Does selecting *Artist* instead not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to move all the music to another folder?
Then arrange by artist, see if it will work.
Also, right click the folder, go to Properties > Customize. See if the folder is optimize for Music